# How to (cleanly) log to a different file per proccess with Ruby on Rails on Phussion Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, passenger

So I want to analize with RequestLogAnalyzer the production logs of a Rails 4 application that runs as a fixed pool of proccesses with Phussion Passenger on Nginx.

The problem is that because the the log file is shared sometimes you get interleaved lines of differents requests and RequestLogAnalyzer disposes that lines. So I said, oh let's fix this simple issue it should be quick.. well still here I am my friends.

First I 've attemped this simple change in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', "#{Rails.env}-#{Date.today.strftime('%Y_%W')}-#{Process.pid}.log"))
```

But only one log file was created.. and the PIDs wasn't of any of the app group proccess that passenger reported via 'passenger-status'.. so I dig dipper and found about the default smart spawn method (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/spawn_methods/#unintentional-file-descriptor-sharing) and obviously when the config was set it was before the child spawn proccess is created.. so wrong attemp.

But in the same article it explained about passenger hooks.. I google a little and voila:

http://pmatsinopoulos.github.io/blog/2016/02/19/making-rails-logger-use-one-log-file-per-process-with-phusion-passenger/

But wait.. what this code is doing, monkey patching and messing this way with the internal workings of the Logging class.. nono there should be something cleaner.

So next I've created a new initializar file with:

```
if Rails.env.production? && defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', "#{Rails.env}-#{Date.today.strftime('%Y_%W')}-#{Process.pid}.log"))
  end
end
```

Simple enough right? Well that is 'kindaof' working: I get different log files per proccess (yeah) but also production.log is still created and logs dumped there..

It looks like someone is caching Rails.logger?? Any idea what is happening here..

Comment: What about keeping a single log file and adjusting it's format to include the PID of the request currently being logged?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom I knew I could do that.. but come'on this should be so difficult.. right!?

Answer (score 0):

In our old rails 4 app we add pid to log.

we add config/initializers/logger.rb

```
class ActiveSupport::Logger
  class SimpleFormatter < Logger::Formatter
    def call(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
      "[#{$$}] [#{timestamp.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')}] #{severity}: #{msg}\n"
    end
  end
end
```